# Qualtrics - Zip Code validation

Tags: validation, qualtrics, zipcode

In a survey I'm programming, there's a question I ask for their zip codes. I have a list of approved zip codes. But I don't want to format the question where I list all 200 of them.

Can anybody tell me where to start to make those listed zip codes "hidden" so when a respondent type in their code it will match what the "hidden" zip codes and will let them go to the next question (validate them to qualify). If not, they will be screened out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing code, you could do a branch for each zip code (yuck).

Alternatively, you could write some JavaScript where you add an onblur event handler to the zip code input field that looks up the zip code in an array, then sets an embedded variable telling you whether it is valid or not.  Then just check the value of the embedded variable in a survey flow branch.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your kind help. After talking to Qualtrics support, they found a way to do that through embedded data so it all worked out! No Javascript coding for me!!! My knowledge of coding (in any form or style) is a level of a kindergartner attempting to color within the lines. The company I work for does not have an IT department, so I googled every forum board I could find to help. Your marketview page was the most helpful so thank-you!! Thank-you, thank-you and again, thank-you! :D